# angularjs how to make dropdown size same as inputbox in a div

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make a html page in my angularjs application. I have a input box and one dropdown side by. My Input box has size and i want to make the dropdown expansion with same size as my input box.

```
My Html Code,
<body ng-controller="Controller">
<h1>Plunkr Example</h1>
<fieldset style="border:1px solid black;">
    <legend>Data</legend>
  <span style="float:right">Check4: <input type="input" id="input"
  ng-repeat="x in string | filter : 'check'" 
  ng-model="x._text"/>
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">True</option>
    <option value="2">False</option>
    <option value="3">Edit</option>
  </select>
  </span>
</fieldset>  
 </body>

And Controller code,
$scope.string = [
    {"_attributes":{"name":"comments"},"_text":"comments"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"check"},"_text":'Some Content Here'},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"value"},"_text":123}
    ]
```

I also made a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BKlieDKvj3QaXtFw8kO1?p=preview) to demonstrate where the current layout is like this, with some gap between inputbox and dropdown. I tried to remove space by padding:0 and margin:0 but no success.

[image]

And what is want is,

[image]

And on click on dropdown the options should come beneath the input box with same size, like below

[image]

Also if user select True/false , the input box should become readonly. It should be editable only if the Edit option is selected.

Please suggest , how this can be achieved. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like following to select option:

```
 <select id="dropdown" ng-model="selectedOption">
    <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.isEditable}}">{{option.value}}</option>
 </select>
```

And use this value as `ng-disabled` as follow:

```
<input type="input" id="input"
    ng-repeat="x in string | filter : 'check'" 
    ng-disabled="{{selectedOption}}"
    ng-model="x._text"/>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Dhananjay. But This is not working for some unknown reason. Also suggest something for length of options.